# ZKemKeeper: Some Real-Time events not triggering

Tags: c#, .net, zkemkeeper

I'm using zkemkeeper dll in a .net windows forms app.
This is my code

```
        objCZKEM.OnConnected += ObjCZKEM_OnConnected;
        objCZKEM.OnDisConnected += objCZKEM_OnDisConnected;
        if (objCZKEM.Connect_Net(IPAdd, Port))
        {
            //65535, 32767
            if (objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 65535))
            {
                // [ Register your events here ]
                // [ Go through the _IZKEMEvents_Event class for a complete list of events
                objCZKEM.OnEnrollFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnEnrollFinger;
                objCZKEM.OnFinger += ObjCZKEM_OnFinger;
                objCZKEM.OnAttTransactionEx += zkemClient_OnAttTransactionEx;
                objCZKEM.OnDoor += ObjCZKEM_OnDoor;
            }
            objCZKEM.RegEvent(1, 65535);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```

I can connect to the device get the logs etc.
OnConnected event is fired.
But no real-time event other than OnAttTransactionEx ever gets called. OnFinger and OnDoor don't work. To be honest I haven't registered a new finger so I don't know if OnEnrollFinger works.

I want to block some users from opening the door using some conditions in my own application. I don't know how I can achieve this. I thought I can use OnFinger event and block the user there. But I'm not sure if it is the way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the latest models' firmware, real time event is disabled due to the business reasons for the cloud solutions from zk. You have to reply on "biometric web api" for getting the real time attendance to your server. If you want to develop only as a desktop application, then you have to poll for the the attendance logs.

For disabling the user from accessing the door, you need to ensure that the user is deleted from the biometric device as soon as you find him/her as ineligible